# Fire jQuery function on radio select for a specific value

Tags: jquery

Okay, I will try to explain this a simply as I can. :)
I have a checkbox that, when checked, fires a jQuery function and selects all radio element options as 'NR', value of 0. This works great, however, I have an additional requirement.

When 1 specific radio button and value is checked, it needs to check the checkbox that fires the function to check all radio element options that are class of 'NR' and display a hidden div.

The code I have display the hidden div but does NOT fire the checkbox function.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
CHECKBOX: <input type="checkbox" name="not_ratable" id="not_ratable" class="form-control">

SPECIFIC RADIO SELECTION: <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="Manager_Staff_Score" id="Manager_Staff_Score_NR" value="0" class="NR">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#not_ratable').click(function () {
        $('.NR').prop('checked',this.checked);
    });
    $('.NR').change(function () {
        if ($('.NR:checked').length == $('.NR').length){
            $('#not_ratable').prop('checked',true);
        }
        else {
            $('#not_ratable').prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
    $("input[type='radio'][class!='NR']").click(function(){
        $("#not_ratable").prop("checked", false);
    });

    // ADMIN/STAFF/MGR ELEMENT


    $("input[name='Manager_Staff_Score']").click(function(){
        var radioValue = $("input[name='Manager_Staff_Score']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue == 0){
                $('#not_ratable').prop('checked',true); (NOT WORK)
                $("#SMEalert").css("display", "block"); (WORKS)
            }
            else {
                $('#not_ratable').prop('checked',false); (NOT WORK)
                $("#SMEalert").css("display", "none"); (WORKS)
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `checked` works better when set on `attr`. Removing the checked-property should work with `prop`, so change your code to:

```
if(radioValue == 0){
    $('#not_ratable').attr('checked','checked');
    $("#SMEalert").css("display", "block");
}
else {
    $('#not_ratable').prop('checked',false);
    $("#SMEalert").css("display", "none");
}
```